# how to transfer data from one server to new one for Civi CRM on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, database, migration

we have data in wordpress based Civi CRM on one server and want to migrate to another server with wordpress. please guide us.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the CiviCRM documentation on moving to a new server. Its not so thorough on WordPress as the other platforms but you should be able to work it all out from the information at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location